# Cannot start Azure VM from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I'm trying to **start an Azure VM using the following PowerShell script**:

```
$subscriptionId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
$azureVM = "VS2017"
$resourceGroup = "VS2017ResourceGroup"
Add-AzureRmAccount # here start interactive login
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
Start-AzureRmVM - -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $azureVM
```

When executing the script, I receive the following response:

```
Start-AzureRmVM : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-'.
At C:\Users\ralbano\Desktop\Senza nome7.ps1:11 char:1
+ Start-AzureRmVM - -ResourceGroupName "VS2017ResourceGroup" -Name $azu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-AzureRmVM], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StartAzureVMCommand
```

I am using Windows PowerShell ISE to run the script.

Am I doing something wrong?

I checked the subscription id and the resource group name and are correct (of course in the sample above the subscription id is a fake). The VM is in *"Stopped (deallocated)"* state on Azure.

Comment: Is the VM a classic VM or an ARM VM? Have to tried Start-AzureRmVM?

Comment: It is NOT a classic VM.

Comment: I tried using *Start-AzureRmVM*, but of course I am changing the *Add-AzureAccount* to *Add-AzureRmAccount* and now the problem is on this Add :-(

Comment: Please try `Start-AzureRmVM` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/start-azurermvm?view=azurermps-4.4.1). I believe `Start-AzureVM` is for starting Classic VMs.

Comment: What's the problem you're getting with Add? Please edit the question and include this information there?

Comment: Please share the error message you get when running `Add-AzureRmAccount`, and edit your code to be current.

Comment: I edited the question and now I have another problem. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

> Start-AzureRmVM **-** -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $azureVM

According to your error message, we should use this command like this:

```
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $azureVM
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.